# How to replace values in one df with values from another df using an if statement

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
df1 <-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), date=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), outcome=c(NA,1,NA,NA,0))
df1
  ID date outcome
1  1   NA      NA
2  2   NA       1
3  3   NA      NA
4  4   NA      NA
5  5   NA       0

df2 <-data.frame(ID=c(3,25,222,415,700), date=c(010215,032412,040513,041015,120314), outcome=c(1,1,1,1,1))
df2
   ID   date outcome
1   3  10215       1
2  25  32412       1
3 222  40513       1
4 415  41015       1
5 700 120314       1
```

If the ID in df1 is in df2 then I want to replace df1$date with df2$date. Also, if ID in df1 is in df2 I want to set df1$outcome = 1. I can do this with this code:

```
df1$date <-ifelse(df1$ID %in% df2$ID, df2$date[match(df1$ID,df2$ID)],df1$date)
df1$outcome <-ifelse(df1$ID %in% df2$ID, 1,df1$outcome)
df1
  ID  date outcome
1  1    NA      NA
2  2    NA       1
3  3 10215       1
4  4    NA      NA
5  5    NA       0
```

but I would like to understand how to do it with one if statement. I have come up with the following code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1$ID[i] %in% df2$ID){
    df1$outcome[i]==1 & df1$date[i]==df2$date[match(df1$ID,df2$ID)]
  }
}

df1
  ID date outcome
1  1   NA      NA
2  2   NA       1
3  3   NA      NA
4  4   NA      NA
5  5   NA       0
```

which runs without errors, but does not complete the desired replacement. Can someone suggest how to modify what I have done to make it work like the first code chunk?

Comment: Your line of code (inside the `if(){...}`) doesn't modify anything. It tests if this entry of `df1$outcome` is 1, `df1$outcome[i]==1`, and if this entry of `df1$date` matches `df2$date` for the same ID. To actually *do* something that lasts, you need to assign something with `<-` or `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue your `for` loop one way would be

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
   if(df1$ID[i] %in% df2$ID) {
     df1$date[i] = df2$date[match(df1$ID[i],df2$ID)]
     df1$outcome[i] = 1
   }
}

df1
#  ID  date outcome
#1  1    NA      NA
#2  2    NA       1
#3  3 10215       1
#4  4    NA      NA
#5  5    NA       0
```

---

However, a non-for loop way would be using `match` where we calculate the indices to replace only once and use it to change `date` and `outcome` values.

```
inds <- match(df1$ID, df2$ID)
df1$date <- df2$date[inds]
df1$outcome[which(!is.na(inds))] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `coalesce` from the `dplyr` package: You do not need to use `if-else` at all

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(df1, left_join(df1['ID'], df2, by = 'ID'))
  ID  date outcome
1  1    NA      NA
2  2    NA       1
3  3 10215       1
4  4    NA      NA
5  5    NA       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lookup:

```
df1 <-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), date=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), outcome=c(NA,1,NA,NA,0))
df2 <-data.frame(ID=c(3,25,222,415,700), date=c(010215,032412,040513,041015,120314), outcome=c(1,1,1,1,1))

col_vec <- c("date", "outcome")
df1[ , col_vec] <- lapply(col_vec,
                          function(x) {
                            mask <- is.na(df1[[x]])
                            result <- df1[[x]]
                            result[mask] <- setNames(df2[[x]], df2$ID)[as.character(df1$ID)[mask]]
                            result
                          })
df1
# ID  date outcome
# 1  1    NA      NA
# 2  2    NA       1
# 3  3 10215       1
# 4  4    NA      NA
# 5  5    NA       0
```